# Gradle platform BOM set version selectively

Tags: gradle, gradle-dependencies, maven-bom

I create [Bom](https://github.com/Monax111/bomExample/blob/main/bom/build.gradle.kts) 
In this BOM constraints many dependency (for example io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging,  ch.qos.logback:logback-classic)
When i add this BOM to my [application](https://github.com/Monax111/bomExample/tree/main/application) and remove version (kotlin-logging, logback-classic) i have error

```
Could not find io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:.
```

But for dependency logback-classic gradle resolve version.

How to reproduce:

1. clone exemple [project](https://github.com/Monax111/bomExample)
2. execute in module bom task publishToMavenLocal
3. remove version [kotlin-logging](https://github.com/Monax111/bomExample/blob/main/application/build.gradle.kts#L18)
4. try build module application

how should i declare dependency not to specify version ?

Answer (score 0):

i use runtime for declar dependency. After Read https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/java_platform_plugin.html#sec:java_platform_separation
i change on api, and it worked